# QProcess cannot start maintenancetool from exe without administrative privileges

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I call QtIFW's maintenancetool.exe from my app.exe to check for updates like this:

```
QString command = QString( "\"C:/Program Files/My Application/maintenancetool.exe\" --checkupdates" );
QProcess process;
process.start( command );
process.waitForFinished();

if ( process.error() != QProcess::UnknownError )
{
    return;
}

QByteArray data = process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

If I run my application, it shows the administration privileges dialog when it does the `maintenancetool.exe --checkupdates` call, as any other applications that needs privileges, and I say yes to accept. Then, my application hangs for a while, and finally process.error() returns a `QProcess::Timedout` error.

If I run my application with administration privileges all goes fine.

Is there a way to run an exe that requires administration privileges from within another exe that doesn't, using `QProcess::start`? Of course, I am trying to avoid the users to have the administration privileges dialog opened everytime they run myapp.exe (only when it looks for updates).

I cannot use `QProcess::startDeattached` since I have to retrieve the output.

NOTE: all works fine too if myapp.exe and maintenancetool.exe are not installed in Program Files, but in any other regular folder (e.g. C:/myfolder).

### Edit

I found out that the problem is that when myapp.exe calls maintenancetool.exe and administrative privileges are requested, maintenancetool.exe takes too long to finish (33 seconds).

The funny part is that the default wait time is 30 seconds

```
bool waitForFinished(int msecs = 30000);
```

So, if I call it this way, it works, but I have to wait 33 seconds!

```
process.waitForFinished( 60000 );
```

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem was solved. Consider adding that solution as a self-answer to your question.

Comment: You should check the return value of [`QProcess::waitForFinished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished). It seems like you're using an online installer, right? For the admin rights issue, you can install your app using admin rights. That would be in the configuration file of the installer. You might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtAutoUpdater.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

It seems that Qt's maintenancetool.exe should not ask for admin privileges at all, that is a bug reported for 3.0.2 (the version I use), and it is fixed in 3.0.4.